# Which websites can be regarded as reliable sources of information for current treatment guidelines for COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, guidelines

I usually get my updates from the dedicated website of the NIH ([link](https://www.covid19treatmentguidelines.nih.gov/)), but this is probably not the only source, and I want to be as up-to-date as I can, so I need to know where to look. There are probably other websites on the same level of the NIH website.

(I realize this MAY seem like an opinion-based question, but still I think that an answer containing the top websites of the most widely-accepted health authorities in the world can be quite objective).

Comment: It will always be opinion-based because there is no worldwide metric that will measure reliability of websites/contents with time passing between links being posted. It would be better to link to specific studies that show good use of statistics and so on. Assuming 'reliability' in this context means e. g. quality with regard to patient safety.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to agree with the opinion-based close votes. A few months ago I would have said the US CDC is one such site, but I'm no longer as certain of that as I was until very recently. But I think your question has value, so I'm going to convert it to a wiki instead of closing it.

Comment: [What are reliable sources?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources) should help. Otherwise, this question is very broad